# Issue upgrading to Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I attempt to upgrade to Rails 5.1.4.  Seems to update without an issue, however, a version check still shows 5.0.4.  Any ideas?

**Ruby Version:**

ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

**Terminal Output:**

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.4
$ gem install rails --version=5.1.4
Successfully installed rails-5.1.4
Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.4
```

Comment: What the output of `rails _5.1.4_ --version` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall all versions of `rails` installed in your system by:
`gem uninstall rails`

It should prompt you with something like below

> Select gem to uninstall:
>    1. rails-4.2.6
>    2. rails-5.1.4
>    3. All versions
>   Choose Option "All Versions" and uninstall all

Install the desired rails version:

```
gem install rails --version=5.1.4
rails -v
5.1.4
```

**Update**: Since you mentioned using `bundle install`, check if `rails` is specified with `5.1.4` in your Gemfile or not.

Comment: No luck.  I uninstall, then before I can reinstall rails, I get a message to run bundle install.  Once that is run, I run a version check and I am still at  5.0.4

Comment: since you ran `bundle install`, are you sure the version listed in your Gemfile is '5.1.4' ?

Comment: That was it.  I had the wrong version in my Gemfile.  Have no idea how I missed that big one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, i met this problem, because you have two versions of rails in your `railties`. You can do this

`gem uninstall railties`

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. railties-5.1.4
2. railties-5.0.4
3. All versions
```

Type 3 to remove all, then you can reinstall `rails 5.1.4` again.

Answer (score -1):

Either use

```
bin/rails -v
```

or

```
bundle exec rails -v
```

to select the version of rails specified in your Gemfile

Or do what I do and install https://direnv.net/ and add a .envrc file to the project. Then when you cd to that project, the path will be updated appropriately and `rails -v` will work as expected:

```
PATH_add "./bin"
```